# NullPointerException Error without line number. How can I get the line number that is causing this error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making an app in android studio. When I click a button my app is crashing. In the log I see the NullPoniterException error, without line numbers that I have written. This is my **Logcat:** (These are internal app codes not written by me. I need the line number that I have written which is causing the error.)

```
2020-01-20 14:06:02.790 16599-16599/com.tanvirgeek.sync E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tanvirgeek.sync, PID: 16599
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7079)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20361)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:825)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:511)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20361)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6355)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20361)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6355)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:401)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20361)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6355)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20361)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6355)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20361)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6355)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:750)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20361)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2896)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1778)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2051)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1663)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7546)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:916)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:718)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:650)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:902)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6802)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

How can I get the line that I have written causing the error? These Line numbers above are internal app codes, not written by me.

**CODE of RecyclerAdapter:**

```
public class  RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyviewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Contact> contactArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Contact> arrayList){

    this.contactArrayList = arrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view,parent,false);
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyviewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(contactArrayList.get(position).getName());
    int msyncStatus = contactArrayList.get(position).getSyncstatus();
    if(msyncStatus == DBContact.SYNC_STATUS_OK){
        holder.msyncStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick);
    }else{
        holder.msyncStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.sync);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contactArrayList.size();
}

public static class MyviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView msyncStatus;
    TextView name;

    public MyviewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        msyncStatus = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgSynch);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: ehm... the line numbers are right there in the stacktrace? What do you mean, without line number?

Comment: please check this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895466/attempt-to-read-from-field-android-view-view-android-support-v7-widget-recycler

Comment: `at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7079)` is right in the stacktrace.

Comment: These are internal app line numbers, Not written by me.

Comment: `ZygoteInit.java:964` means line 964 in file named `ZygoteInit`. What do you mean by *written by me*?

Comment: Most of the line numbers are  internal app codes. Not written by me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve NullPointerException error in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303544/how-to-solve-nullpointerexception-error-in-android)

Comment: Post your code so we help you

Comment: Error in your adapter Or Viewholder class.Can you share code of adapter & viewholder class?

Comment: Android studio should show the line number, which is causing the error, isn't it? They are showing the line numbers of internal app codes which are irrelevant.

Comment: To show line number in **Android Studio** check this [How to show line numbers in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056913/how-to-show-line-numbers-in-android-studio)

Comment: Are you showing a number on button text?

Comment: Hi, can you describe how this happens? is it hapening at the app start or after an event?

Comment: After an event. After clicking a button. Yes I am trying to show a list of name by a recyclerview.

Comment: I have added the codes of RecyclerAdapter class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is: you can't get the line number.

This is simply because the error occurs at the `RecyclerView` level which is not aware of how or where the view is created (your code).

This being said, this error is quite common. In your case the error comes from a null View returned by your `onCreateViewHolder`. All you have to do to fix the problem is to return the `view` instance.

Comment: Those who created android studio could've give the line numbers. Looks like android studio is not too perfect. :(

Comment: I agree there is room for improvement here. The least I would expect is that Android Studio marks the `return null` statement. Seeing the annotation @NonNull, this makes me more surprised the method is not marked.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning `null` in onCreateViewHolder method. You should return `view`.

Change `return null;` to `return view;`